# Adding Zoom Level to Multiples Point in Large KML File

Tags: excel, google-maps, zooming, kml, google-earth

I have a data set of all cities and towns coordinates for a country (roughly ~30k points). Additionally, I also have the zoom level that it should be displayed at in google earth.

Right now, I am going from excel to KML through an application called earthpoint, which does not support the zoom functionality I am looking for (i.e., all points are displayed at all zoom levels).

How could I append the zoom level data to this KML file?

If I convert the excel file to the KML file, is there a way I could write a script automate adding in the zoom level code for each point? If so, how would I do this?

Best,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

The zoom-level in KML can be overridden through a [LookAt](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#lookat) or [Camera](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#camera) element specified either in an individual placemark or a parent Document/Folder.

To specify a document-level zoom-level to your KML, only need to specify a single LookAt or Camera element in the root Document. When KML file is first opened, the root LookAt/Camera will be used to adjust the initial view including its zoom level.

```
<Document>
 <LookAt>
  <longitude>-122.363</longitude>
  <latitude>37.81</latitude>
  <altitude>2000</altitude>
  <range>500</range>
  <tilt>45</tilt>
  <heading>0</heading>
  <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
 </LookAt>
 <Placemark>
 </Placemark>
 ...
</Document>
```